# Append to div and keep scrolled to bottom rendering issue IE

Tags: javascript, html

I'm appending children div's to a parent div and then scrolling the parent div to the bottom.

In IE, the elements appear to "swim" and kills the eyes. This doesn't happen in Chrome, Firefox or Safari.

```
$('#foo').append($('<div>' + new Date() + '</div>'));
$("#foo").scrollTop($("#foo")[0].scrollHeight);
```

I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1hw0Lomt/3/) showing the problem.

Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: Which version(s) of Internet Explorer are affected by your issue? This may be of significant help in guiding future answers.

Comment: I was only able to test in 9, 10, 11 and Edge.

Answer (score 0):

After some more playing I see the issue is relating to IE not knowing the height of the element being added hence the rendering issue.

A hack is to append the div (has to render first), get the div height (as it could vary based on content), and then set the height to this value, and only then scroll the div:

```
$('#bar').css('height', $('#bar').css('height'));
```

If there is a more elegant way please let me know.